# Error in Firebase UI dependency

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies, firebaseui

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

--> implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1'

when I add firebase Ui database dependency then Gradle shows error

Comment: try the below answer buddy

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 3):

in your app.gradle add this below code

In your app/build.gradle file add this dependency and try

```
dependencies {
// FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.3'
}
```